# Exim mailing list with remote recipients

Tags: exim, spf

### Premises (fictional names)

- `foo` is an **external** domain, of which the MTA is out of my control;
- `foo` has **SPF** setup such that `mine` servers cannot send email as `@foo`;
- `bar` is **another external** domain, of which the MTA is also out of my control;
- `bar` does **SPF checking** on incoming mails to reject explicit fails (RFC recommendation and common practice);
- `mine` is a **local domain**, of which MTA is the exim I'm configuring, it's been working for several years, but only now we noticed a misbehaviour;
- `List <list@mine>` is a **mailing list** of which `Bob <bob@foo>` is a member (note: effectively this could also be a "forwarding address", but it's simpler to think of it with lists);
- `list@mine` members are stored on a mysql **database** that is managed elsewhere (which means it's not a static list);
- `Alice <alice@bar>` wants to **send** an email **to** `List <list@mine>`.

### What I need

#### Short version

How to configure (without recompiling) exim so `Alice` can send an email to `List` which would be redirected to `Bob`.

#### Long version

This configuration has been working for several years for the cases where either the sender was `@mine` or all the receivers were `@mine`. With a configuration like this:

```
open_lists:
  driver = redirect
  data = ${lookup mysql{...}}}
  forbid_pipe
  forbid_file
  no_more
```

**What doesn't work**: the case where both sender and receiver are externals.

**Why**: for some reason (this is the misbehaviour I was talking about) exim preserves the original **envelope sender** (aka MAIL FROM per the RFC), which `bar` rejects due to an SPF  fail.

I'm aware of [SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) and its [experimental implementation on exim](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/SRS).
However besides being experimental it requires recompilation to be enabled. It wouldn't be terrible if there was an updated ubuntu **ppa** with compiled packages ready, though I haven't found one.

I'm also aware of [exim's rewriting](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html) which has a flag `F` to change the envelope sender (From), but that flag can't be used with `headers_rewrite`. It's only available on the rewrite section.

Basically I'm looking for a way to fix the **envelope sender** which is expected to be `list@mine` in this case, be it through rewriting or SRS, it must only be maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [Signing the Return Path Address.](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/signing-return-path-addresses-with-exim/)  My implementation assumes local domains, but I have seen similar approaches used for forwarded addresses.  Handling bounce messages is a little more difficult as you will need to reconstruct the destination address from the signed address.

If you are forwarding for an external address, you may want to add a sender or resent-from header.  This may resolve issues where the recipient system verifies the sender address.

I am using the Ubuntu heavy build of Exim, and in some cases it will add some resent headers.

Comment: I will try that, however if I got that right than the recipient server must check for the signed return path before SPF failure of MAIL FROM. Is that a common behaviour?

Comment: @JanSegre The signed return path will replace the envelope address (MAIL FROM).  This should pass SPF validation.

Comment: Ok, this helped a lot, but it seems that I'll have to spend some more time to understand how to build the proper __return_path__ because the one from that post only works for local domains. But it's a huge plus to verify that the __MAIL FROM__ is changed when __return_path__ is set on the transport.

Comment: @JanSegre  I would build a local part like `listname=sendername=senderdomain=hashvalue`.  Verified bounces would be forwarded back to `sendername@senderdomain`.  This breaks down quickly if there are multiple forwarding hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the **return_path** in the transport that does the redirect:

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-generic_options_for_transports.html